# Cross-platform Filesystem and ACLs for installation on Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, ext4, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am deploying NextCloud on my Raspberry Pi. I am stuck on what I know is an inefficient way to design and run a system. Currently the configuration sits on an external drive with ext4 file system. I am using ACLs to secure the files on ext4 file system. I however have MS Windows boxes at home. For the sake of other members of the family, I run a cron job that copies files from the ext4 drive to an NTFS drive.

**Is there a way I can apply ACLs while having a cross platform file system to use the same backup drive on WIndows and Linux.**

Comment: This is of course a native UNIX topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you like to use compatible `"ACL"`s, you need to use `ZFS` as the other filesystems on Linux only support the old `ACL` proposal that was withdrawn in 1997.

`ZFS` supports the current `ACE` standard that is also used e.g. in NFSv4 and NTFS.

If you however like to share this over the network, you need to search for the modified `SAMBA` source from Oracle that has been modified to support native `ACE`s. This however requires you to run Solaris or FreeBSD on the file server as Linux currently only supports the withdrawn `ACL` proposal.

From your comments, it seems that you are only interested in basic file permissions. In this case, it is sufficient if you either install `NFSv4` client software on Windows or a `SAMBA` server on Linux.

Comment: My primary concern is a cross platform filesystem that I can apply permissions (using chmod). I hope that's what your answer is towards. I'll be research on this :)

Comment: I *think*  *BSDs are not entirely supported in all rpi versions.

Comment: If you only care about what chmod does, why do you mention ACLs? Linux does not support ACLs via chmod.

Comment: That's has to be my lack of knowledge. I saw chmod setting permissions on a file or folder and compared it to ACLs